# jQuery sum the values of table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hello i have this table 
[image]

i want to get the total of each row in the total column 
  jQuery

```
  //Monthly Marketing Cost Report

         $.get('/dashboard/costs', function(data){
            $.each(data,function(i,value){
                var leads = $('#leads');
                var budget_total_year = $('#full_year_cost');
                var budget_total_month = $('#share_cost');
                var budget_per_lead = $('#cost_per_lead');

                leads.append('<th>' + value.olxTotal + '</th>');
                budget_total_year.append('<th>' + value.budget_total_year + '</th>');
                budget_total_month.append('<th>' + value.budget_total_month + '</th>');
                budget_per_lead.append('<th>' + value.budget_per_lead + '</th>');
            })

        })
```

HTML

```
  <tbody id="tableData-marketMonth">
                                        <tr id="leads">
                                            <th>Leads</th>
                                         </tr>
                                         <tr id="full_year_cost">
                                             <th>Full Year Cost</th>
                                         </tr>
                                         <tr id="share_cost">
                                             <th>{{date('F')}} Share of Cost</th>
                                         </tr>
                                         <tr id="cost_per_lead">
                                             <th>Cost per Lead</th>
                                         </tr>
                                    </tbody>
```

i was going to calculate the total through php but i though it can be easier
using jQuery just putting the sum of each row at the end 
  Thank you very much

Comment: Unless you want to change the numbers and calculate live on client-side doing the calculation on php is much easy and simple. If you have a database table... even better to get the sum with query.

Comment: i want to calculate it on client side but i need help i can't figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create variables before the loop. add to the variables in the loop and then assign the sum at the end.

```
 $.get('/dashboard/costs', function(data){

            var sumLeads = 0;
            var sumFullYearCost = 0;
            var sumShareCost = 0;
            var sumCostPerLead = 0;

            var tr_leads = $('#leads');
            var tr_budget_total_year = $('#full_year_cost');
            var tr_budget_total_month = $('#share_cost');
            var tr_budget_per_lead = $('#cost_per_lead');

            $.each(data,function(i,value){


                tr_leads.append('<th>' + value.olxTotal + '</th>');
                tr_budget_total_year.append('<th>' + value.budget_total_year + '</th>');
                tr_budget_total_month.append('<th>' + value.budget_total_month + '</th>');
                tr_budget_per_lead.append('<th>' + value.budget_per_lead + '</th>');

                sumLeads += value.olxTotal;
                sumFullYearCost += value.budget_total_year;
                sumShareCost += value.budget_total_month;
                sumCostPerLead += value.budget_per_lead;
            });


            tr_leads.append('<th>' + sumLeads  + '</th>');
            tr_budget_total_year.append('<th>' + sumFullYearCost  + '</th>');
            tr_budget_total_month.append('<th>' + sumShareCost  + '</th>');
            tr_budget_per_lead.append('<th>' + sumCostPerLead  + '</th>');    
   });
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works as on the first feild leads i get 56 as total
but on the rest i get nothing and i get this error on console budget_total_year is not defined

Comment: I have updated the code by moving the row assignments outside the loop. Also I have changed the row names so we know the error is about the row or your data.

Comment: Thank you very much you saved my day works just fine <3

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
$('#tableData-marketMonth tr').each(function () {
    var row = $(this);
    var rowTotal = 0;
    $(this).find('th').each(function () {
        var th = $(this);
        if ($.isNumeric(th.text())) {
            rowTotal += parseFloat(th.text());
        }
    });
    row.find('th:last').text(rowTotal);
});
```

NOTE: change 'th' to 'td' if you have td's.  Looking at your jquery, it looks like you are appending th's.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer i tried it but i got this https://ibb.co/gT07yYw

Comment: I would need to see your final HTML of that table screenshot, can you post that as well? You could copy the html out of developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

Example for leads row using `Array.map` and `Array.reduce`. Use `jQuery` to get the `td` elements.

```js
var leads = $('#leads');
const total = leads.children('td').toArray().map(x=>Number(x.innerHTML)).reduce((sum, x) => sum + x)
leads.append(`<th>${total}</th>`);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer i tried but it didn't work 
all the table earased and i got the sums on the 1st column and the rest of the table is empty

Answer (score 0):

You can use my written code to vote if you like it...

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>MAX ATK</th>
            <th>MAX DEF</th>
            <th>MAX HP</th>
            <th>Overall</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="combat">8170</td>
            <td class="combat">6504</td>
            <td class="combat">6050</td>
            <td class="total-combat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="combat">8500</td>
            <td class="combat">10200</td>
            <td class="combat">7650</td>
            <td class="total-combat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="combat">9185</td>
            <td class="combat">7515</td>
            <td class="combat">9185</td>
            <td class="total-combat"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //iterate through each row in the table
    $('tr').each(function () {
        //the value of sum needs to be reset for each row, so it has to be set inside the row loop
        var sum = 0
        //find the combat elements in the current row and sum it 
        $(this).find('.combat').each(function () {
            var combat = $(this).text();
            if (!isNaN(combat) && combat.length !== 0) {
                sum += parseFloat(combat);
            }
        });
        //set the value of currents rows sum to the total-combat element in the current row
        $('.total-combat', this).html(sum);
    });
});
```